# Routing all URL requests in CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

Is there a way to capture all URL requests and route them? Sort of like:

```
$route['everything'] = "controller";
```

Comment: How do you want it routed? do you want `everything` as a method or a parameter to a method?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$route['(:any)'] = "controller";
```

Comment: I tried that, didn't work. Turns out I had my controller messed up, after a bit of fixing it works. Thanks for the help.

Comment: No problem. Just in case your interested here's a technique to store routes in the database. http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/154170/

Answer (score 2):

```
$route['(:any)'] = "your_controller/your_method/$1";
```

This should work. This way, what is in `(:any)` will be passed to your method as a parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Try this -

```
$route[':any'] = 'path of the default controller';
```

you can get it's documentation [here](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html)